# Vinagre host key?

Tags: shortcut-keys, remote-access, vinagre

Does vinagre (Remote Desktop Viewer) has host key, usually it is <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd> ?

This is helpful to switch between remote keyboard shortcuts and host keyboard shortcuts.

I use this program frequently in Ubuntu 12.04 and this would be really useful

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2035317

https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Vinagre